# Version One - Fetch All teams & members associated with a project

Tags: api, rest, versionone

I'm trying to fetch the teams along with team members for a project using version one query.v1 endpoint. As I'm looking at the fields of Scope (using meta.v1), I can see Members, so for fetching teams I'd have to do a subselect Member and find Team name.

Is it possible to directly query the teams for a project and its members ?

i.e Instead of this,

```
  "from": "Scope",
```

using

```
  "from": "Team",
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to get team and team members, perhaps this will help?

```
 var query = '''
{
  from: TeamRoom,
  select: [
    Name,
    Team,
    Team.Name,
    Mascot.Content,
    {
      from: Participants,
      select: [Name, Avatar.Content, Email, Phone, Username]
    }
  ]
}
''';
```